# How can I statically register structures at compile time?

Tags: rust

I'm looking for the right method to statically register structures at compile time.

The origin of this requirement is to have a bunch of *applets* with dedicated tasks so that if I run `myprog foo`, it will call the `foo` applet.

So I started by defining an `Applet` structure:

```rust
struct Applet {
    name: &str,
    call: fn(),
}
```

Then I can define my `foo` applet this way:

```rust
fn foo_call() {
    println!("Foo");
}
let foo_applet = Applet { name: "foo", call: foo_call };
```

Now I would like to register this applet so that my `main` function can call it if available:

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    match AppletRegistry.get(args[1]) {
        Some(x) => x.call(),
        _ => (),
    }
}
```

The whole deal is about how `AppletRegistry` should be implemented so that I can list all the available applets preferably at compile time.

Comment: Have you considered a build script? I don't know if they would be applicable to you (if this is a library, you're kind of out of luck)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.

One of the conscious design choices with Rust is "no code before `main`", thus there is no support for this sort of thing.  Fundamentally, you need to have code somewhere that you explicitly call that registers the applets.

Rust programs that need to do something like this will just list all the possible implementations explicitly and construct a single, static array of them.  Something like this:

```rust
pub const APPLETS: &'static [Applet] = [
    Applet { name: "foo", call: ::applets::foo::foo_call },
    Applet { name: "bar", call: ::applets::bar::bar_call },
];
```

(Sometimes, the repetitive elements can be simplified with macros, *i.e.* in this example, you could change it so that the name is only mentioned once.)

*Theoretically*, you could do it by doing what languages like D do behind the scenes, but would be platform-specific and probably require messing with linker scripts and/or modifying the compiler.

*Aside*: What about `#[test]`?  `#[test]` is magic and handled by the compiler.  The short version is: it does the job of finding all the tests in a crate and building said giant list, which is then used by the test runner which effectively *replaces* your `main` function.  No, there's no way you can do anything similar.

Comment: *have a macro somewhere* — I don't see a macro in your example, and I can't figure out how one would play in here. Could you expand that bit a little more? Also, what about concepts like `#[test]`, which you annotate a function with and then it gets magically run from the test main. Would it be possible to do something similar as a user?

Comment: _No there's no way you can do something similar._ - Using [compiler plugins](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/compiler-plugins.html), but it's not yet stable if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 7):

You can.

You need to use the [inventory crate](https://crates.io/crates/inventory). This is **limited to Linux, macOS, iOS, FreeBSD, Android, and Windows** at the moment.

You need to use [`inventory::submit`](https://docs.rs/inventory/0.1.9/inventory/macro.submit.html) to add it to a global registry, [`inventory::collect`](https://docs.rs/inventory/0.1.9/inventory/macro.collect.html) to build the registry, and [`inventory::iter`](https://docs.rs/inventory/0.1.9/inventory/type.iter.html) to iterate over the registry:

```
use inventory; // 0.1.9
use std::{collections::BTreeMap, env};

struct Applet {
    name: &'static str,
    call: fn(),
}

// Add something to the registry

fn foo_call() {
    println!("Foo");
}
inventory::submit!(Applet {
    name: "foo",
    call: foo_call
});

// Build the registry

inventory::collect!(Applet);

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let mut registry = BTreeMap::new();

    // Access the registry
    for applet in inventory::iter::<Applet> {
        registry.insert(applet.name, applet);
    }

    if let Some(applet) = registry.get(&args[1].as_ref()) {
        (applet.call)();
    }
}
```

Running it shows how it works:

```
$ cargo run foo
Foo

$ cargo run bar
```

Comment: Could this be done in a default trait function implementation so that library end users don't have to worry about registering something themselves and can just rely on implementing a certain trait?

Comment: @PopFlamingo no idea — try it and let me know!

Answer (score 3):

This is not a direct answer to your question but just FYI... For ELF binaries, I could achieve something similar to GCC's `__attribute__((constructor))` with

```
fn init() { ... }
#[link_section = ".init_array"]
static INIT: fn() = init;
```

This is obviously a deviation from Rust's design philosophies.  (Portability and what @DK calls "no code before `main`" principle.)

`INIT` can also be an Rust array.  You might need to pay more attention to alignments.

Comment: I *knew* there was a linker section for this, but damned if I could find what it was called.  Of course, as you say, this is *horribly* non-portable...