# Is there a way to import a module in Rust knowing its directory but not its filename?

Tags: import, module, rust

I'm writing a game-playing AI in Rust. The strategy module includes a folder with standardized modules that handle specific situations. I want to be able to create a new module anytime I think of a new situation that I would like handled.

I can accomplish this in Node. For example, in an MVC setup, you might have

```
├── src
    ├── controllers
        ├── index.js
        └── ...
    ├── models
        ├── index.js
        └── ...
    └── views
        ├── index.js
        └── ...
```

with a controllers/index.js file containing

```js
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Imports
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Models
const models = require('../models');

// Modules
const fs   = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const controllers = {};

const basename = path.basename(__filename);
fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) &&
           (file !== basename) &&
           (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    controllers[file.slice(0,-3)] = require(`./${file}`)(models) ;   
  });
```

Can I accomplish something similar in Rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to import a module at runtime; Rust is a statically-compiled language.

The closest thing you could do would be to write [a build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) that enumerates your filesystem and generates the appropriate `mod` and/or `use` statements.

> ```js
> require(`./${file}`)(models)
> ```

Rust also doesn't have "default exports" of imports, so this pattern cannot exist. You'd have to call a specifically-named function from the module.

See also:

- [How can I statically register structures at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32678845/155423)

Comment: Then it seems like I need an index file in which I manually import each script. This setup lends itself to some annoying "gotchya"s when you're adding hundreds of scripts. Is there a better pattern?